# How to add calender event into recipient Outlook calendar via "clicking a link"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, outlook-calendar

I am sending event details in ics format as mail attachment and the recipient can open this file in Outlook calendar and save the event.

Now I want to provide a link in the mail on clicking it the event details will be saved into the clients (recipient's) outlook calender. How can i accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/outlook-help/create-an-add-to-calendar-link-in-an-email-message-HA102114161.aspx

Basically you attach an ical link to your email and then you can link directly to that.

Comment: thanks for the immediate response. i am providing an ics file as attachment. i am sending mail to the client in html format with the ics file as attachment from my asp.net application. The recipient can add the event to his calender by opening the ics file. But now i want provide a button in the mail on clicking it the event is created in clien's outlook calender.

Comment: Aha, I didn't realise you were doing it via a .net application - I just assumed you were doing it via the Outlook client.